# Вытесняются элементы за границу экрана Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Уже этот xml вдоль и поперек перебрал, но результата 0. Подскажите где косяк?
Так должно быть:

[image: Как должно быть]

Тут длинный текст вытесняет кнопку за экран:

[image: Кнопка уходит за экран]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/main_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@drawable/separator"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            >

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="0.4">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/firstheader"
                    android:textColor="#00b0e4"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:id="@+id/report_button"
                    />
            </GridLayout>

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/secondheader"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill|left"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                    />

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button21"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button22"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />


                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:id="@+id/button23"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText" />

                <Button
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:id="@+id/button24"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:id="@+id/button25"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText" />

                <Button
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:id="@+id/button26"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="@string/othertest"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
                    android:id="@+id/otherschedulebutton"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"

                    />

            </GridLayout>

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                >


                <TextView
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="@string/thirdheader"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill|left"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn31"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn32"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn33"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn34"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn35"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn36"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <Button
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="@string/othertest"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
                    android:id="@+id/other_status_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
                    />

            </GridLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете вес, но при этом не обнулили соответствующий параметр вьюхи. В вашем случае вам надо ширину обнулить вместо `wrap_content`.

Также совершенно нет никакого смысла в вашем случае использовать `GridLayout`. Можно ограничиться `LinearLayout` Тем паче, что `GridLayout` не должен бы вообще отображаться нормально в `ScrollView`

---

Вот такая разметка позволит правой кнопке занять всё нужное ей место, а левому тексту - всё оставшееся

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="@string/firstheader"
        android:textColor="#00b0e4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:id="@+id/report_button"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: С весом это я уже начал играться позже. Так же использовал LinearLayout, но в этом случае улетали только кнопки, которые были возле текста. Как быть с тем чтоб в LinearLayout с горизонтальной ориентацией элемент не выпихивало текстом за границу?

Comment: @user200303, привёл в ответе пример реализации. Детали зависят от конкретной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете layout_weight, то надо сделать layout_width равным 0 для горизонтального расположения или layout_height = 0dp для вертикального.
Для вашего случая должно быть так:

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="**0dp**"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="@string/firstheader"
                android:textColor="#00b0e4"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                />
```

Comment: Это уже была попытка что-то исправить. На результат оно не влияет